# How to use two arguments with multiple words

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is an example of my problem:

```py
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx, *, arg, arg2):
       await ctx.message.delete()
       r = requests.get(f"https://example.api/image?first_text={arg}sec_text={arg2}")
       await ctx.send(r)
```

If I execute the command like this: `{prefix}example argument one text, argument two text`

It should return `example.api/image?first_text=argument one text&sec_text= argument two text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With keyword parsing you can have only **one** keyword variable that takes all text provided as documented [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).

You need to split its content yourself:

```
@bot.command()
async def example(ctx, *, arg):
       await ctx.message.delete()

       # split the ONE argument into two
       arg, arg2 = arg.split(",", 1)

       r = requests.get(f"https://example.api/image?first_text={arg}sec_text={arg2}")
       await ctx.send(r)
```

See: [str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

---

Sidenote: You might want to fix your URI - it missess a `&` before the 2nd argument:

```
r = requests.get(f"https://example.api/image?first_text={arg}&sec_text={arg2}")
```